# jquery select siblings 'until'

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a DOM in the form of

```
<input class="parent"></div>
<input class="child"></div>
<input class="child"></div>
<input class="parent"></div>
<input class="child"></div>
...
```

which I know is not Right and the right way to do this would be to reform the HTML, but lets say that is not possible.

How can I get jquery to select all children of one parent (that is select all .children until .parent)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

jQuery 1.4 now has the .nextUntil(selector) function:

```
    $('div.parent').toggle(
        function() {
            $(this).nextUntil('div.parent').hide();
         },
        function() {
            $(this).nextUntil('div.parent').show();
        }
    );
```

Answer (score 8):

You can iterate through the [`nextAll`](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/nextAll) `div` siblings elements until you find the following `.parent`, check this [example](http://jsbin.com/ihovi):

```
$('.parent').click(function() {
  $(this).nextAll('div').each(function() {
    if ($(this).is('.parent')) {
      return false; // next parent reached, stop
    }
    $(this).toggleClass('highlight');
  });
});
```

Markup used:

```
<div class="parent">parent 1</div>
<div class="child">child</div>
<div class="child">child</div>
<div class="parent">parent 2</div>
<div class="child">child</div>
<div class="parent">parent 3</div>
<div class="child">child</div>
<div class="child">child</div>
<div class="child">child</div>
```

...

Comment: I will give this another shot. I had done it this way but it caused much slowness, due to some extra DOM element I didn't include (wrappers). I didn't think to just return false (I did checks all the way around).

I will optimize and try it again. Thanks!

Comment: This was a huge help. Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

*** See @foson answer for jquery 1.4+ ***

Check out Ben Almans [until utils](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-untils-plugin/).

It gives you 3 usefull methods: nextUntil, prevUntil, parentsUntil.

Comment: I ended up going with this util, very easier and does the above but I don't have to maintain it ;)

Comment: It is worth to check @foson answer that tells about nextUntil

Answer (score 0):

I think no need for the above custom functions, JQuery supports this functionality by `nextUntil(selector, filter)` function, but you should add filter to only apply your script to the filtered elements not to all next elements:

```
//hide all .child elements
$('div.child').hide();
$('div.parent').click(function() {
  //Toggle (show or hide) only .child elements until finding .parent element.
  $(this).nextUntil('div.parent', 'div.child').slideToggle('slow');
});
```