# jQuery to find nearest Div of Parent

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, siblings

I am trying to learn jQuery with the following scenario. For this, I tried the following jQuery after reading multiple SO questions; but it did not work

```
$(this).closest('.viewLogText').parent().find('.reportLog').css("display", "none");
```

**Scenario:**

There are three child div elements in a div that has Css class “repeaterRecord”. The child divs are with css classes - repeaterIdentifier,   viewLogTitle and reportLog.

There are two divs with this structure (div that has Css class “repeaterRecord”).

[image]

The div with viewLog class is as shown below.

```
   <div class="viewLogTitle">
        <div class="viewLogText">
            View Report Log
        </div>
        <div>
            <img alt="Expand" src="Images/PlusIcon.GIF" class="expandLogIcon" />
            <img alt="Collapse" src="Images/MinusIcon.GIF" class="collapseLogIcon" />
        </div>
    </div>
```

When the collapseLogIcon image is clicked, I need to hide (only) the nearest div with “reportLog” class (at the same level of "viewLogTitle"). How can we do it using jQuery?

**Updated Working Example**:

http://jsfiddle.net/Lijo/L9w4F/11/ and 
http://jsfiddle.net/Lijo/L9w4F/8/ and 
http://jsfiddle.net/Lijo/L9w4F/12/

**REFERENCE**:

1. [Efficient, concise way to find next matching sibling?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4933236/efficient-concise-way-to-find-next-matching-sibling)
2. [jquery select siblings 'until'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1829811/jquery-select-siblings-until)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `siblings()` method:

```
$(this).closest('.viewLogText').siblings('.reportLog').hide()
```

You can also try the `hide()` method which is same as `.css("display", "none");`

Answer (score 5):

You can use `.siblings()` to find the nearest `div`.

**[API HERE](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/)**

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest using:

```
$(this).closest('.viewLogTitle').next('.reportLog').hide();
```

Note that the filter passed to the `next()` method (`'.reportLog'`) means that the next sibling element of the `viewLogTitle` element will be affected *only if* it matches that selector. If the next-sibling of the `.viewLogTitle` will *always* be the target (the HTML isn't going to change), then the filter is unnecessary and may be omitted.

Or, if they don't always follow consecutively (but the 'nearest' is always the one to be affected), for following siblings:

```
$(this).closest('.viewLogTitle').nextAll('.reportLog:first').hide();
```

Or for preceding siblings (if the `.reportLog` precedes the `.viewLogTitle`):

```
$(this).closest('.viewLogTitle').prevAll('.reportLog:first').hide();
```

References:

- [`:first` selector](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/).
- [`next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/).
- [`nextAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/nextAll/).
- [`prevAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/prevAll/).

Comment: The filtering selector in `next` is not needed with a single element

Comment: That's true, so far as it goes; but the intent of passing the filter was to account for those times when the next sibling might *not* be the desired target. Though, in fairness, I should have explained that intent. **edited**

Comment: If it might not be that, then `next` is not appropriate :P

Comment: Hence the subsequent suggestions. =)

Comment: Yeah, the only reason I am even commenting is that any time I have seen `next` used with a filter, it has been because the author has misunderstood `next`. `next(filter)` intuitively looks like it's gonna find the next element that matches `filter`, but instead it simply takes the next element sibling and returns it IF it matches the filter, otherwise returning nothing.

Comment: Agreed; and you were right to comment, my explanation was an absolutely glaring omission. =)